# Regex: Delete everything (all the text) before a particular word, but not after it

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

```
Chances are your color consultant has worked with hundreds of different clients over the years. WORD_1 They Have the Knowledge and Expertise
```

I need to delete all text before **WORD_1** but not after it.

**The output should be:**

```
WORD_1 They Have the Knowledge and Expertise
```

My regex is not very good:

FIND: `((?s)((^.*)WORD_1)).*`

REPLACE BY: `(leave empty)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `.+(?=\bWORD_1\b)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
.+              # 1 or more any character
(?=             # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    \bWORD_1\b      # WORD_1 surounded by word boundary. Will not match AWORD_1 or WORD_10
)               # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: thank you. But your solution is good in one case: if there are no blank lines between more paragraph. But see this case:  https://pastebin.com/E1L68qrr  In this case, your regex don't delete everything before the word **`WORD_1`**

Comment: this is a much better solution. I modify your regex a little bit  **`(?s).+?(?=\bWORD_1\b)`**  or second solution  **`(?s)\A.+?(?=\bWORD_1\b)`**

Comment: @HellenaCrainicu: Or tick `. matches newline`

Answer (score 1):

The simple way :

Find what : `^.*WORD_1(.*)$`
Replace with : `WORD_1\1`